# What are internal clustering index for binary data ? And if possible applicable to massive cluster ?

Tags: clustering, big-data

I was wondering what are the current existing internal clustering index for binary data.

I know already the silhouette and Davis Bouldin for euclidian space, i suppose they work as well in binary space using Hamming distance for example, tell me if i'm wrong.

We can use the distance to points from centroid per cluster as an indication compared to the average distance point to point, but the cost of the computation of the similarity matrix is a bit restrictive when it comes to deal with Big data so if it exist :

- Any binary internal clustering index
- Applicable to Big data
- Other internal index even in euclidian space

Thank you in advance for your wise suggestions

Peace